# extract geometry from map in website

Tags: web, geometry

I want to extract this route on the web map in this link
https://scenicbyways.info/byway/80452.html
I don't know a ton about the web. there are instances where I have I added .geojson at the end of link and it returns geometry and attributes which I go onto scraping with python. that does not work here and I am not planning on doing this manually